# Best way to execute combination of different functions in Python

Tags: python, function, design-patterns, functional-programming

Suppose there are `n` functions defined, each of which represents some action, and functions, whcich represent combinations of these actions:

```
def all_actions():
    action1()
    action2()
    action3()
    ...
    actionN()

def combination_of_1_and_2():
    action1()
    action2()

def combination_of_1_and_3():
    action1()
    action3()

def combination_of_1_2_and_3():
    action1()
    action2()
    action3()

.....
```

How to implement this functionality in Python without writing a separate function for each combination?

**UPDATE**

If you consider this question as opinion-based, you have to consider any question on [best practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices) as opinion-based and not allow it. But definition says that: `Coding best practices are a set of informal rules that the software development community employ to help improve the quality of software.`, which means they are all informal and based on community opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One dynamic way to achieve this will be to store the reference to all the functions in a list (or dictionary), and call the functions based on the indices. For example::

```
my_action = [action0, action1, action2, .... , actionN]

my_action[1]()   # perform action1()
my_action[N]()   # perform actionN()
```

And define single function to perform action based on indices:

```
def do_action(actions):
    for action in actions:
        my_action[action]()
```

Using `do_action` function, instead of defining custom functions for all the combinations of actions, you can just pass the indices of those actions. For example:

```
do_action([1, 3, 5])

# Equivalent of:
#    action1()
#    action3()
#    action5()
```

And for performing all the actions, you can simply pass `range(N)`:

```
do_action(range(N))
```

Comment: is it possible to use python's built in itertools' combination and permutations?

Comment: I don't think OP's intention is to find all possible combination. I think OP is looking for an elegant way to access different combination of actions without copying/writing the same thing again and again, which I tried to cover here

Comment: Although someone doesn't like my question, I think it is there's good chance of discussion. What if the actions take different parameters?

Comment: Having actions with different parameters will entirely change the context of the question you initially posted, and both the answers posted here won't be valid. I think you need post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If you put all the functions into an array, you can simply call functions based on the array index. Thus to make combinations, you would use a function like this:

```
def combination(fns):
    for i in fns:
        actions[i-1]()
```

For example:

```
def action1():
    print('action1')
    
def action2():
    print('action2')
    
def action3():
    print('action3')
    
actions = [action1, action2, action3]
    
def combination(fns):
    for i in fns:
        actions[i-1]()
        
combination([1, 3])
```

Output

```
action1
action3
```

You could then write `all_actions` like this:

```
def all_actions():
    for i in range(len(actions)):
        actions[i]()
```

You could also just pass an array of actions to a `combination` function. For example:

```
def combination(fns):
    for fn in fns:
        fn()
        
combination([action1, action2])
```

Output:

```
action1
action2
```

Comment: Although someone doesn't like my question, I think there's a good chance of discussion. What if the actions take different parameters?

Comment: To do that you're probably getting to the point where it's just as easy to write out the function calls individually anyway.